# Pinocchio 70th Anniversary Font

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to identify the font used to write "Pinocchio" in the [70th Anniversary Wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA9w2.jpg) without success. Even though I believe the 'P' is an artwork, I couldn't find a (close) match on MyFonts, FontSquirrel or Identifont.

[image]

Could you help me? I would like to recreate a translated version of it 'cause the only one I could find was assassinated when cropped >.<

Comment: Sorry, _who_ exactly was assassinated? I didn't realise graphic design was such a deadly business!

Comment: The translated version. Whoever published it cut-off part of the fairy's wings and part of the ocean. I don't have any commercial intentions nor copyright infringements, but I need to practice and it gives me itches look at it that way ¯\_(ツ)_/¯